# Doubtful Linear Algebra in Probability

Tags: probability

Gentlemen, I apologize for this task design. The question is how is this expression ${p}_{l} = b_{1}(\frac{3}{2})^l + b_2$ obtained? Is this a linear algebra question? But such a stunt I've never seen.
Sorry for the picture again.

[image]

Comment: The title of the question should have something to do with the specific question itself. Imagine what would happen if everyone who need help to solve a problem would use the title “Please help me with the solution of the following problem”.

Comment: It's difficult to know how to answer you.  How much of this solution do you understand?  The problem can be solved with methods from linear algebra but need not be.  It's a homogeneous, second-order, linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients, and you can find many pages on the Web that will tell you how to solve those, without ever mentioning eigenvalues.

Comment: Just this transition itself is not clear. Why is this $p_l$ equal to linear combinations of eigenvalues?

Comment: (Women do math, too)

Comment: @saulspatz thank you, I found articles that explain this situation

Answer (score 0):

You are following the discussion up to this point?
$(p_{l+1},p_{l}) = (0,p_1)A^l$

If $A$ is diagonalizable, $A = PDP^{-1}$
$A^2 = PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1} = PD^2P^{-1}\\
A^l = PD^{l-1}P^{-1}PDP^{-1} = PD^lP^{-1}$

$A^l = P\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1^l\\&\lambda_2^l\end{bmatrix}$
That is a linear combination of the $l^{th}$ powers of the eigenvalues of $A.$